# Not able to add short code to Mobileconnect

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect

I have got a short code with me but I'm not able to find a way to add this to my Mobileconnect account. Please let me know that what I'm missing.

[image]

Comment: Is the shortcode available on the MobileConnect administration page?

Comment: Short code is not visible on admin screen as well. Do I have to ask salesforce rep for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process for adding short codes is something that is handled by the Salesforce Marketing Cloud provisioning team so you will need to contact your SF rep.